# Changes to managed package while security review is in progress

Tags: managed-package, security-review

We are submitting our app for security review but wanted to still continue feature development of our managed package. I had the following questions regarding it:

- Can we continue development of the managed package once it is in security review?
- Can the packaging org be updated?
- If we want to release another package or patch to our current subscribers while the review is still in progress, how do we go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you can continue dev while on security review - this is why you supply to them a test org with the package installed.
2. The security review team will check the package version that you have submitted, if you have a new package version, you can ask them to check the new one instead.
3. you can release a new version, but the security review team will approve the version that you have submitted (unless you have asked), so after they have approved your package version, you can request approval for your new version, usually this new version request gets approved automatically (unless you have made critical changes).

Comment: what will happen, if salesforce team sends few observations? Say I submitted 1.1 for review and for my feature dev I had 1.4 in place. Now when i get observations, I will create 1.5 or 1.4.<patch> and will send, is it fine? or i need to have the same 1.1 org/comps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know
try submitting your own question